# VBA - How to read an sql output and then apply if else condition?

Tags: vba

I have a VBA macro that reads data from a file and then update the data in the Accounting Software. I want to put a condition in the code where it will first read the VENDOR number from the file and then run a SQL query to check the TAXCLASS against that VENDOR number. If the TAXCLASS is 1 then it will go with 'If' statement and if the TAXCLASS is 2 then it will go with 'else' statement.

1st option:

```
SQL = "select taxclass1 from vendortable where vendorid = 12345"
if taxclass = 1 Then
first condition
else
second condition
End If
```

2nd option:

This option works but it only checks whether there is any value in TACLASS or not and doesnt serve the purpose.

```
If CheckTax(Vendor) = True Then
APIBH.Fields("AMTGROSTOT").Value = ImportedAmount  * 1.1
Else
APIBH.Fields("AMTGROSTOT").Value = ImportedAmount  * 1
End If
```

```
Function CheckTax(Vendor As String) As Boolean

    Vendor = Replace(Vendor, Chr(34), "")
    Dim VIEW1 As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim SQL As String
    SQL = "SELECT TAXCLASS1 FROM APVEN where VENDORID = '" & Trim(Vendor) & "'"

    VIEW1.CursorType = adOpenStatic
    VIEW1.LockType = adLockReadOnly
    VIEW1.CursorLocation = adUseServer
    VIEW1.Open SQL, A4W
    If VIEW1.RecordCount <> 0 Then
        CheckTax = True
        VIEW1.Close
        Set VIEW1 = Nothing
        Exit Function
    End If
    CheckTax = False
    Set VIEW1 = Nothing
    Exit Function
    
End Function
```

I am a beginner in VBA and was wondering if it possible or not?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dlookup function like this  (12345 = number)

```
if nz( DLookup("[taxclass1]","vendortable","[vendorid]=" &  12345),0)=1 Then
first condition
else
second condition
End If
```

if 12345 = string then use this

```
if nz( DLookup("[taxclass1]","vendortable","[vendorid]='" &  "12345" & "'"),"") = "1" Then
first condition
else
second condition
End If
```

Comment: Isn't dlookup used for MS Access?

Comment: Yes dlookup used in MS Access. and from your comment i understand that you are using it in different application. so witch is it , and what is the data source ?